# Objects between functions within larger function in R (reproducible code)

Tags: r, function, global-variables

This has to simple but it has me confused for the life of me.

I'm trying to get objects (numeric variables, data frames, etc.) created in a larger function *into a smaller function within that larger function*.

The output of the example functions below should be a data.frame with 20 rows, but I only get "test". Would someone please kindly explain this object function behavior in R and how to get created objects between the functions? Thanks in advance!

```
testfunload <- function(test){

###All my different tries to get test dataframe into testfunload function
  txt <- get("test")
  try1 <- get(test)
  try2 <- get(paste0(txt))
  try3 <- get(paste0(test))
  try4 <- get(test)
  try5 <- test
  try6 <- get("test")

  print(try1)
  print(try2)
  print(try3)
  print(try4)
  print(try5)
  print(try6)
}

###Testing with test data.frame in local environment
testfunload2 <- function(){
test <- data.frame(i1=rep("i",20), i2=rep("I",20))
testfunload(test="test")
}

###Testing with test data.frame in local environment
testfunload2global <- function(){
  test <<- data.frame(i1=rep("i",20), i2=rep("I",20))
  testfunload(test="test")
}

###PROBLEM:Doesn't have data.frame only "test" as char
testfunload2()
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"

###PROBLEM:Doesn't have data.frame only "test" as char
testfunload2global()
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
```

Desired output:

```
   i1 i2
1   i  I
2   i  I
3   i  I
4   i  I
5   i  I
6   i  I
###on for 20 rows etc.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I'm sorry but this code doesn't really make much sense to me. Is all the printing necessary? What are you trying to do with all the `get()`s? And keep in mind `<<-` just to the parent environment where the function was **defined**, not where it was called from. Also, do you happen to have a variable in the global environment named `test`? Hard to tell from the example

Comment: This is a very unusual type of thing to do in R (by that I mean the heavy use of `<<-`, `get()` and trying to access objects in functions without explicitly passing them as arguments. Typically, this is because these things make things *more* complicated. Is there any particular reason why you wouldn't just pass the objects you want as explicit arguments?

Comment: The above was just an example. In reality I have a larger function creating a data.frame for a smaller function to use, create an output by defining a global, go back to the larger function for the final output.

Comment: I was trying to get the dataframe named test into the second function. The heavy use of get() and paste() were all my different tries to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I would rethink that whole approach, particularly assigning to the global environment. It'll just create headaches. Generally you want to stick to functions that return explicit values, and pass those values on to other functions as arguments as needed.

Comment: In this case I am forced to pass a data.frame as values are created together

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really follow why this approach would be necessary. Probably you will have better luck using `get()` if you are more careful about specifying what environment it looks in (see the arguments for `get()`) but broadly speaking I would strongly recommend against the approach at all.

Comment: So why aren't you passing the data.frame rather than a character version of the name of the variable? Plus within the function, the `test` parameter becomes a local variable containing the value `"test"`. But it seems like you expect it to get the value from the parent calling frame. Maybe you want `get(test, envir=parent.frame())` but this is a very fragile way to code things. Just pass the data as a proper parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks a bit like a complicated way to pass variables to a function. Maybe you can get what you want using the `...` argument?

If you want to access the calling scope, though, you can look at `parent.frame()`. It gives you the environment in the scope where your function is called.

Consider this function:

```
f <- function() {
    e <- parent.frame()
    with(e, x + y)
}
```

It evaluates `x + y` in the calling scope -- you are getting dynamic rather than lexical scoping, in a way.

So with these functions, you are passing `x` and `y` to `f` without doing so explicitly.

```
g <- function(x, y) f()
h <- function(x) { 
    y <- 2
    f()
}
```

They will work like this:

```
> g(1, 1)
[1] 2

> h(3)
[1] 5
```

It would be *much* simpler just to make `x` and `y` parameters of `f`, of course.